# zsh_history stores non-ascii character with strange encoding

Tags: zsh, zshrc

When I open my .zsh_history file, I found that some non-ascii characters in my history have strange encoding or something like that.

Here is a minimal example:

First, the `.zshrc` is

```
# zshrc
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
```

I typed some commands with chinese character, `exec zsh` to save the history, and read `.zsh_history` file.

```bash
echo 字串測試 一二三
exec zsh
tail -3 .zsh_history
```

The result is replaced with some random weird characters.

```
echo 孃串測試 一亃七
exec zsh
```

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEcJg.png)

Also, when I use vim or any text editor to open this file, it opens this file use `latin1` encoding and displays the following:

```
echo å­·ä¸²æ¸¬è©¦ ä¸äº¬ä¸©
exec zsh
```

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlpr9.png)

I cannot find an option to fix this, and I'm guessing it's an encoding problem.
How can I force zsh to save the history in utf-8 encoding or there is another way to fix this?

Comment: Updated. The images are still there just in case that someone might not have proper font/encoding setting to see those characters.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue (in Hebrew). Any luck figuring it out?

Comment: Also suddenly Hebrew characters are all replaced with number codes. saying 'file .zsh_history' tells me  
.zsh_history: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text. Now I wonder how to set history to UTF-8?

Answer (score 4):

I found this https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00154.html
and it seems that this behavior is intended.

The reply said that

> This isn't a bug, the history file is saved in metafied format. If you
> want to print it outside zsh you can use this simple program.
>
> ... (a simple C program)

I guess the better way to browse the history in zsh shell is `fc -l -i 1 | vim -`. (maybe `man zshbuiltins` for more options)